# How to convert a <table> from column into row when mapping a JSON object using React?

Tags: html, json, reactjs

In **React 16.11.0**, I used `map()` function for a simple JSON object to access the values of each elements. When **ReactDOM** renders the `content`, the *table* will display a list of values in **column** for each elements of `data`:

```js
const data = [
  { Name: "Jame",   Email: "jame123@gmail.com",    ID: "1568132456", City: "New York" },
  { Name: "Harris", Email: "harris456@yahoo.com",  ID: "7666487798", City: "Chicago" },
  { Name: "Daisy",  Email: "daisy789@hotmail.com", ID: "2177897432", City: "Los Angeles" },
  // etc...
];

const Table = ({data}) => {
  const head = (
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  );

  const body = data.map(element => (
    <tr key={element.ID}>
      <td>{element.Name}</td>
      <td>{element.Email}</td>
      <td>{element.ID}</td>
      <td>{element.City}</td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>{head}</thead>
      <tbody>{body}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Table data={data}/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

The table output will display these values below:

[image]

Instead, what I want is the values will be displayed in **row** for each elements like this table below:

[image]

How to convert the table in this case?

Comment: Just like you rendered this, you can map over the data like you do and make a const called rowNames, one called emailAdresses, ids and cities for example and just fill them the same way you're filling them now (all data.Name in rowNames, all data.Email in emailaddresses etc) and then render them row by row. Seems pretty straightforward, unless I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create rules for each row and loop on these rows, then on your data:

```
const data = [
  { Name: "Jame",   Email: 'jame123@gmail.com',   ID: "1568132456", City: "New York" },
  { Name: "Harris", Email: 'harris456@gmail.com', ID: "7666487798", City: "Chicago" },
  { Name: "Daisy",  Email: 'daisy789@gmail.com',  ID: "2177897432", City: "Los Angeles" },
  // etc...
];

const rows = [
  { name: 'Name', render: (item) => item.Name },
  { name: 'Email', render: (item) => item.Email },
  { name: 'ID', render: (item) => item.ID },
  { name: 'City', render: (item) => item.City },
];

const body = rows.map(({ name, render }) => (
  <tr key={name}>
    <td>{name}</td>
    {data.map((item, i) => (
      <td key={i}>{render(item)}</td>
    ))}
  </tr>
));

const content = (
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>{body}</tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(key => (
  <tr key={key}>
    <td>{key}</td>
    {data
      .map(element => element[key])
      .map(value => (
        <td key={value}>{value}</td>
      ))}
  </tr>
));
```

You probably want to find better keys for the second `map`, the one that generates `td`.